# Edit breadcrumble for EditUser

Tags: moodle

I created a Moodle plugin based on the edit user admin page `moodle/admin/user.php`.

Everything works, except the breadcrumble from the top navigation is still pointing to the edit user admin page.

This is the starting script of the plugin that creates the invalid breadcrumble:

```
<?php
require('../../config.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/course/lib.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/report/log/locallib.php');
require_once($CFG->libdir.'/adminlib.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/lib/tablelib.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/user/filters/lib.php');
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/user/lib.php');

  // Check if user is allowed to browse users
  admin_externalpage_setup('editusers');

  $sort         = optional_param('sort', 'name', PARAM_ALPHANUM);
  $dir          = optional_param('dir', 'ASC', PARAM_ALPHA);
  $page         = optional_param('page', 0, PARAM_INT);
  $perpage      = optional_param('perpage', 30, PARAM_INT);

  $returnurl = new moodle_url('/report/gnppoints/index.php', array('sort' => $sort, 'dir' => $dir, 'perpage' => $perpage, 'page'=>$page));


  $sitecontext = context_system::instance();
  $site = get_site();

  $strshowallusers = get_string('showallusers');

  $ufiltering = new user_filtering();

  echo $OUTPUT->header();
```

I don't know where the breadcrumble is created. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First add this in `settings.php`:

```
$ADMIN->add('reports',
            new admin_externalpage('reportgnp', get_string('pluginname','report_gnppoints'),
            $url
          ));
```

Then replace

```
admin_externalpage_setup('editusers');
```

by

```
admin_externalpage_setup('reportgnp');
```